# Макрос VBA для смены формата даты Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Нужно перед импортом xls-файла в dbf привести все даты к единому формату. Но проблема в том, что макрос меняет формат в столбцах вплоть до наличия пустой ячейки, а дальше отказывается работать. Привожу код ниже:

```
Sub data()
Worksheets("ðîçïë.(ðàõ.1)").Range("M7:M10000").NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
Worksheets("äåìîíòàæ(ðàõ.2)").Range("M7:M10000").NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
Worksheets("ïëîìá.(ðàõ.3)").Range("M7:M10000").NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
Worksheets("ïëîìá.(ðàõ.3)").Range("R7:R10000").NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
Worksheets("ïëîìá.(ðàõ.3)").Range("W7:W10000").NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
Worksheets("ìîíòàæ(ðàõ.4)").Range("M7:M10000,R7:R10000,W7:W10000")
.NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
Worksheets("ïîâ³ðêà,ÖÑÌ(ðàõ.5,6)").Range("G7:G10000").NumberFormat = 
"DD/MM/YYYY"
 Worksheets("ðåìîíò(ðàõ.7)").Range("K6:K10000").NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
 End Sub
```

Comment: Замените код в стартовом сообщении (копировать нужно не при английской раскладке). В чем проблема: меняет формат там, где не нужно или где-то отказывается работать? Отказывается работать - на какой строке ошибка? *Worksheets("ïîâ³ðêà,ÖÑÌ(ðàõ.5,6)")* - не два ли листа пытаетесь указать?

Comment: 2)Код рабочий, но в самом файле не происходит изменений.

Comment: Ссылаюсь на один лист, просто таково его название.

Comment: код рабочий, формат ячеек меняется. Ищите проблему в другом. Не называйта процедуры, переменные зарезервированными словами (*data* - данные), могут быть проблемы

Comment: Спасибо за потраченное время. Но я бы не стал писать сюда, если бы мог сам найти ошибку.

Comment: Но у меня Ваш код работает. Покажите пример в файле. Возможно, при подготовке примера обнаружите ошибку.